# Problems using bootloader on STM32F030 - no ack from erase extended for page

Tags: stm32, bootloader

I am using an ESP32 to write firmware into an STM32F030 using the ST bootloader, using the information in the ST AN3155 document. The details of the extended erase command are on page 25.

I have successfully dealt with the gotcha where the bootloader reboots after an unprotect command, but when I try to send an extended erase command, I have hit a problem. If I erase the entire flash using the Mass Erase (0xFFFF) option, it works... but I have configuration information in the last page, so I want to erase just the code pages (0..12 of 16 pages). According to the datasheet, the page erase time is 30ms, so a one-second wait for an ack should be enough.

This is the message sequence if I try to erase just one page: have I made a mistake in the Extended erase message?

```
Unprotect
tx 73
tx 8c
rx 79

Sync
tx 7f
rx 79

Erase extended
tx 44
tx bb
rx 79

tx 00
tx 01
tx 00
tx 00
tx 01
rx -
No ack at Erase2
```

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved. The first two bytes of the Extended Erase command indicate how many pages to erase. If the number is N, then **N+1** pages are erased: so, to erase one page, N must be zero. This is the correct sequence to erase one page (page 0):

```
Erase extended
tx 44
tx bb
rx 79

tx 00
tx 00
tx 00
tx 00
tx 00
rx 79
```